# 16.04 WiFi Repeatedly Connects and Disconnects on Certain Networks

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Warning, noob here!

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Sony Vaio VPC-SC1AFM laptop. I can connect to my work's network just fine. At home it will connect to my home network and within a minute or two disconnects only to reconnect again shortly. It will continue this indefinitely.

This laptop uses the Intel Centrino WiMAX 6250 driver.

Not sure if this helps, but if I type

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
```

I get

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 5f
   serial: 64:80:99:28:80:50
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-51-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=10.21.8.180 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:37 memory:c7400000-c7401fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: enp5s0
   version: 06
   serial: f0:bf:97:60:1b:4d
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:31 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enx64d4da297fbe
   serial: 64:d4:da:29:7f:be
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no
```

This is when connected to my stable work network.

Comment: What channel are you using? Are you using WPA2-AES? Does the problem improve if you get closer to the router?

Comment: I am not sure what channel I am using but I'll try to find out when I am home. I believe I am using WPA2-AES. And no, the problem doesn't change regradless of where I am relative to the router. If it helps, this laptop dual-boots windows 7 and I have no problem with the wifi when using windows or on other devices on the same network. It seems like my android phone also has trouble connecting to the wifi when ubuntu is also having trouble. It does the same connection/disconnection cycle.

Comment: `sudo iwlist wlan0 freq` will tell you what channel you're connected to. You can also go to the routers web admin page and check in the wireless tab. I'll be set to a channel number, or to auto. You can also check that the encryption is set to WPA2-AES. If you have an Android phone/table, please install `WiFi Analyzer`.

Comment: Okay, Im on channel 11 I believe and I am using WPA2-AES. The problem doesn't seem to change with my distance from the router.

Comment: @heynnema any chance you could continue helping me or point me to a place where I could find more help? If not, I understand. I don't mean to nag you and I really appreciate the help you've given me thus far. Any chance a fresh install would help? Thanks!

Comment: Log into your router's admin page, and go to the wireless settings, and change `channel` from 11 or auto, to channel 1, and save, retry connectivity. If it's not any better, change the channel to 6, save, and retest. If neither channel 1 or 6 made any improvement, set it back to 11 or auto (whatever was there first) and save. You can also try, in terminal, `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off`. Report back.

Comment: You can also boot to a Ubuntu 16.10 Live DVD in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and see if the wireless problems go away.

Comment: Changing to channel 1 seems to have worked! Thanks a lot for your help, I'm now using Ubuntu full time.

Comment: I now seem to have a problem reconnecting after suspending the system. I understand this is a common problem on Itel wireless cards, but it doesn't happen on my work network. Any insights?

Comment: Try the `power off` command that I gave you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an interference problem from neighbouring wireless networks, or from appliances (like wireless telephones) that operate in the same frequency spectrum.

From the comments...

Log into your router's admin page, and go to the wireless settings, and change channel from 11 or auto, to channel 1, and save, retry connectivity. If it's not any better, change the channel to 6, save, and retest. If neither channel 1 or 6 made any improvement, set it back to 11 or auto (whatever was there first) and save. You can also try, in terminal, `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off`.

Update...

channel 1 seems to have solved the problem.